# Positioning logic for a network request in a React/Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, redux-thunk

I have a React component that renders items on a page. The items are retrieved from the network.

These items should be retrieved and rendered when the component is loaded.

There will be a mechanism to update the items after the component has loaded too.

My first thought is to position the network request inside the `componentDidMount` function.

Would doing this break any of the best practises associated with redux and unidirectional data flow/immutability?

Instead, should I send an action to the store and rely on redux middleware to perform the network request (which will then eventually change the store and cause a re-render of the component)?

Comment: If your data is local, do it inside the `componentWillMount`,if your data is global then do it by calling an `action`.

Comment: If you make this the answer I will accept...

Comment: @anuragasaurus By putting the logic in componentWillMount, the DOM for the component will not be present. So would it be possible for the async network call to return before componentDidMount was called? If this happened, would I get unexpected behavior? I can't visualize what would happen....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is local, do it inside the componentWillMount,if your data is global then do it by calling an action.

So basically making async call in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` is same. Most probably, async call in `componentWillMount` wont return before `componentDidMount` is fired. But it will return before than if you make the same call in `componentDidMount`.

Making async call in `componentDidMount` makes it clear that component will first render without data and then re-render when data arrives which is implicit in `componentWillMount`.